# [Error expected identifier or '(' before '{' token]

Tags: c++, c

I have a project and two files in the project are named as d2.c. and student.txt.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define appendData();
#define data();
#define editRecord();
#define searchRecord();
#define deleteRecord();
int main(void)
{
    struct person
    {
        char stdNumb [20];
        char firstName [20],lastName [20], icPass [20], nationality [20], gender [20], dateOfBirth [20];
        char contact [20], address [30];
    };
    char choice;
    while(1)
    {

        printf("\n============================");
        printf("\n            MENU");
        printf("\n============================");
        printf("\n1. ADD");
        printf("\n2. SEARCH");
        printf("\n3. EDIT");
        printf("\n4. DELETE");
        printf("\n5. EXIT");
        printf("\n============================");
        printf("\n\n");

        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        choice = getche();
        switch(choice)
        {
        case'1' : //call append record
            data();
            break;
        case'2' : //call search record
            searchRecord();
            break;
        case'3' : //edit record
            editRecord();
            break;
        case'4' : //Read all record
            deleteRecord();
            break;
        case'5':
             exit(0);
        defaut:
            printf("ss");
        }
    }
}

void data()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct person obj;

    fp=fopen("D:\\data.txt","a");

    printf("\n============================");
    printf("\n            ADD");
    printf("\n============================\n\n");
    printf("Student Number: ");

    scanf("%s",&obj.stdNumb);
}
```

Now the Compiler is giving me a warning as

```
warning: useless type name in empty declaration [enabled by default]
```

I cannot understand why this warning is there because I have to use this struct in other files of my project.

Comment: Warnings and errors in C or C++ always indicate a line number. Use this information. Or at least indicate in your question what it is. Formatting your code consistently and sensibly will also help solve issues with inspection.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  To indent code, select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it.  Make sure your code is indented in a more or less orthodox style, preferably with blanks rather than tabs and with tabstops set at 4 (this is roughly what SO assumes anyway).

Comment: In C++ you can do `person obj;` instead of `struct person obj;`.

Comment: Note that you define `struct person` inside `main()`; it is not defined in the function.  This is likely the problem you're running into.

Comment: Your problem is that you have `#define data();` and then you declare a function `void data()`. The `#define` makes `data` a macro whose value is just `;`. Your `#define`s really don't make much sense here.

Comment: Instead of just making things up (like `#define data()`) you should find a good book or tutorial, follow it closely, and **understand** what it is you're writing.

Comment: The error message in your title doesn't match the warning message in your question. Please update your question to indicate which diagnostic you're actually getting.

Answer (score 3):

The `#define`s at the start of your file cause those function names to be replaced with semicolons.  In particular, this one:

```
#define data();
```

is causing this:

```
void data()

{
```

to become this:

```
void ;

{
```

which causes your error, since the function name and parenthesis are missing and an unneeded semicolon is added.